# How to find the OPA url after deploying opa as a side car on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, open-policy-agent

I have deployed OPA as a side car with my application.Now I want to find out the OPA url because I want to put it as an endpoint. OPA documentation has mentioned that we can find out the OPA url after deploying, using "OPA_URL=$(minikube service opa --url)" and then this command "curl $OPA_URL/v1/data". So I want to know about how can I do the same thing with GKE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, OPA binds on `0.0.0.0:8181` so you would be able to reach it at `POD_IP:8181`. You can control this by setting `--addr`.

For example, if you only want to expose the OPA API inside the pod (which makes sense when you're running it as a sidecar), you can do the following:

```
opa run --server --addr localhost:8181 --diagnostic-addr 0.0.0.0:8182
```

This will:

- Start opa as a server (`opa run --server`)
- Bind the OPA API on localhost only
- Bind the diagnostic API on all interfaces (e.g., so that health checks from the kubelet can be configured)

If you want to expose OPA as a service outside the pod (in which case, it's not really used as sidecar anymore) you would have to create a Kubernetes Service object like you would for any other workload.

Comment: This made me clear.thank you very much for your response.